# Im Trying To Upload My Unity VR Game to Meta Quest App Lab, But I Recieve This Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

[image: the error I get]

i attempted to upload my unity VR game to meta quest 2 app lab, and I received this error. I have tried multiple times to google is or looked on forums, but I have not found any support.

Comment: You need to create a keystore and sign your app with it. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-keystore-manager.html https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: i already have a keystore but im not sure how to sign my app with it.